# Shopify shows CSP error when I try to redirect my app within the iframe

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, content-security-policy

I am using Kyon147/laravel-shopify.

I followed the steps based on the documentation and created an app which I can install to a test store.

My problem is:
I created a plan, but no matter what I'm doing, I keep getting the error message:

*Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin https://admin.shopify.com' from frame with URL.....*

I don't have any custom routes, and I also tried creating a middleware that adds

`$response->header('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors https://{$user->name} https://admin.shopify.com");` with no success.

The app is running from my local Ubuntu Apache and served to Shopify via ngrok. Laravel version is: 8.83.27

Can you please help me with what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle https://admin.shopify.com/store/your-shopify-store now in addition to the old your-shopify-store/admin routes. Not sure you have a CSP problem, so much as handling the new routing to Apps. Check the documentation for that. It is recent to the last few months anyway.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone who struggle with the same, please read this thread for the solution I had with Shopify. It works now.

https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/embedd-app-redirection-with-unified-admin/m-p/1911767/thread-id/86921#M86968